# Continuous Integration with React Native

Tags: continuous-integration, react-native

I am new to iOS, Can someone please tell me how can I set up CI for react native? I currently use codeship but I don't think they offer anything for iOS. Any suggestion on any hosted CI tool which supports bitbucket? Thanks

Comment: Unit tests? Probably plain mocha + chai combo on circleCI or travisCI should work.

Comment: Bit of a broad question, this. The CI issue is a bit of a distraction - don't you first have to work out what kind of tests you want to run and then how to automate them? Or do you just mean automating a build?

Comment: If you need a CI service for iOS apps you can try ours https://www.bitrise.io/ - disclaimer: I'm the CTO & Cofounder. You can run custom scripts and have sudo access on the build virtual machines so you can install the tools you want to use if it's not preinstalled. Full list of installed tools and VM info: http://devcenter.bitrise.io/docs/virtual-machine-updates.html

Comment: I am just trying to figure out how to automate a build. I know how to write tests but not sure how would u automate a build

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a [React Native Starter App](https://github.com/bartonhammond/snowflake) for both Android & iOS that uses Bitrise.io and they support BitBucket.  The tests are run with Jest and have over 86% coverage.  There's a [video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYafslJvXz8&list=PLPDajyixAsuMKSDMel9x6pzmBuklZq4ci) detailing the CI process. Swapping out Github for Bitbucket is trivial, during the registration process you'll be prompted for a vendor (Github/Bitbucket).  After that everything should be the same. Note: I am the developer.

Comment: Is this totally free?

Answer (score 10):

I'm using [buddybuild](https://buddybuild.com/) for my React Native apps. It's going awesome so far. I felt bitrise a little bit complicated and I got some problems during my builds, Buddybuild is totally transparent. It helps me not only with Continuous integration, but also with:

- **Checking for Xcode compatibilities:** with each new version and beta of Xcode, buddybuild will take the most recent successful build of your app, run it against the newest version of Xcode and email you the results of any potential breaking changes.
- **First Class Test Support:** Run tests UI and Unit tests on simulator, emulator and physical devices.
- **Static Code Analysis**
- **Code Coverage:** know exactly how much of your code base is being exercised during testing.
- **Instant Deployments:** Organize your testers into groups to configure which builds they get, and how often they should receive new versions of your app.
- **Publish to the Play Store and App Store:** Automatically deploy your app to the Play Store or App Store!

And also the  **Continuous Integration** will build both the Android and iOS versions of your app. Simply onboard the app twice and select iOS then Android to have both versions built.

Comment: Buddybuild was bought by Apple, and discontinued both its free plan and its Android support. So there is no point to use Buddybuild for react native anymore.

Comment: @Laurent yeah, right now I am using Microsoft AppCenter

Answer (score 1):

You can use [circleci](https://circleci.com) which has good integration with other tools like Fastlane, [Here how you set up](https://bamlab.gitbooks.io/a-gentle-introduction-to-mobile-development/content/ci/ci_1.html)  [another](https://joshhornby.co.uk/blog/react-native-and-continuous-deployment) And greate Talk by [talk by Joe Stanton @ React Meetup London](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9j5Uam6ORLI)  one more greate article by [Ramesh Nair](https://hiddentao.com/archives/2017/02/17/continuous-integration-for-react-native-with-testfairy-testflight-deploy/)