# react-native: what automation CI tool is the best?

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, appium

**React native community: What CI tool do you use?**

Our team has built a react-native ios app.  We also have a separate test team that created an appium test suite to run against the app.  The test suite can be run locally, but we are ready to setup a CI flow to build our app, run the appium tests against it, and eventually fill out this flow with deployment, code coverage, etc.

We have invested some time in attempting to get a build pipeline working within CircleCI to generate a build and then pipe the artifact to the appium project, with limited success. We reached out to CircleCI support and they have indicated that they do not officially support react-native at this time.

**We are now exploring other CI options and are interested to see what others in the community are already using successfully.**

Some research has lead us to several possiblities.  Related research:

- [Continuous Integration with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381230/continuous-integration-with-react-native)
- http://macoscope.com/blog/automate-testing-and-build-delivery/
- http://blog.thebakery.io/continuous-integration-for-react-native-applications-with-fastlane-and-bitrise-ios-version/

Possible options:

1. BuddyBuild
2. Bitrise + Fastlane
3. TravisCI
4. Jenkins

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: @BSMP this question is totally okay. Maybe quora is a better place to discuss.