# Obfuscate entire React Native app including JavaScript code

Tags: android, ios, react-native, proguard, reverse-engineering

How to obfuscate my react-native JS code? I have set the following in my build.gradle file:

```
release {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
 }
```

Here is my proguard-rules.pro file (default):

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.3/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

But still after unzipping the apk I can find my JS components name, variables and url's

Answer (score 53):

As your React Native JavaScript code is built upon native code for Android and iOS, an entire obfuscation process would consider all three codebases:

#### Obfuscate Java code for Android

Fortunately your project already includes the `Proguard` obfuscator, which can be enabled as following:

1. Update your release configuration in the `build.gradle` file located in `android/app/` folder:

   ```
   def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

   android {
       // other config omitted for brevity
       buildTypes {
           release {
               debuggable false
               shrinkResources enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
               zipAlignEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
               minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
               useProguard enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
               setProguardFiles([getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'])
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Enable ProGuard obfuscation and edit rules accordingly in `proguard-rules.pro` file located in `android/app/` folder.

   The following line of code needs to be commented out (add `#` at beginning of line):

   ```
   #-dontobfuscate
   ```

   At this stage building the release version of your Android app should contain obfuscated Java code. Check it by analysing your APK, where you should find function calls such as `a`, `b` instead of the their actual names.

*Code above referenced from [Maria Korlotian's Medium post](https://medium.com/@korlotyan/android-react-native-obfuscation-eeeec5760d07). Check also [latest default React Native ProGuard configuration](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/proguard-rules.pro) from GitHub repository.*

From Android 3.3 beta onwards, a more optimised obfuscator called [R8](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/11/r8-new-code-shrinker-from-google-is.html) can be used.

#### Obfuscate Objective-C code for iOS

There is no built-in library in the iOS project that will obfuscate your code, therefore an external package has to be used. [PPiOS-Rename](https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename) and [ObjC-Obfuscator](https://github.com/FutureWorkshops/Objc-Obfuscator) are two options here. The detailed documentation can be found in their GitHub repositories.

#### Obfuscate JavaScript code

This would be the most important part of the obfuscation as our actual code is written in JavaScript. The [react-native-obfuscating-transformer](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/react-native-obfuscating-transformer) npm package can be used here:

1. Add the package to your project

   ```
   npm install react-native-obfuscating-transformer --dev
   ```
2. Add / update the CLI configuration in [`rn-cli.config.js`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/understanding-cli#cli-configs) at the root of your project, where `android` and `ios` folders reside.

   ```
   module.exports = {
    getTransformModulePath() {
      return require.resolve("./transformer")
    },
   }
   ```

   Create this file if it does not exist yet.
3. Create the `transformer.js` file also at the root and specify [configuration options](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/react-native-obfuscating-transformer#configuration) as appropriate:

   ```
   const obfuscatingTransformer = require("react-native-obfuscating-transformer");

   module.exports = obfuscatingTransformer({
       /* Insert here any required configuration */
   });
   ```

   Pay attention especially to the scope of the obfuscation process, which by default targets only files in `src/` folder (node_modules is excluded by default).

---

Having all the above stated, obfuscating your app will not make it inherently secured – although security **and** obscurity can be better than only the former, there are many other security enhancements (if not requirements) that can be implemented in a React Native app. This includes storing sensitive information in secure storage ([Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) in Android / [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services) in iOS), implementing [certificate pinning](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29988/what-is-certificate-pinning) if appropriate, and others.

Other useful links:

- [Secure Storage in React Native](http://randycoulman.com/blog/2017/07/25/secure-storage-in-react-native/) by Randy Coulman
- [Strengthen TLS in React Native through Certificate Pinning](https://hackernoon.com/strengthen-tls-in-react-native-through-certificate-pinning-e6e8d53e8254) by Skip Hovsmith

Comment: are there any other javascript obfuscation tools apart from react-native-obfuscating-transformer as this has issues

Comment: @SamyakUpadhyay have you tried opening an issue in GitHub in that regard? This is the only one I know about for React Native specifically, which is based on [`javascript-obfuscator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-obfuscator).

Comment: @Siavas how can i know my apk is obfuscate?

Comment: @Siavas Can you tell me how to check the result of my obfuscate code  ?

Comment: @OttohHidayatullah after you compile the APK, analyse it and check the classes.dex file inside the APK. The methods from your code should be replaced by letters such as 'a', 'b', etc. The [image](https://medium.com/@angelhiadefiesta/obreverse-engineering-apks-guide-to-see-if-obfuscation-works-64d56f18ec12) in this post shows an example.

Comment: When we build a react native project to native app (example android), I think we don't need obfuscate Javascript code because the built app (apk) does not include Javascript code?

Comment: @RobinHuy actually the native app still contains the JavaScript code. You would be able to observe that when you get errors, for example, if the app was built for development. This generally called "bridging" architecture is rather unique to React Native. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124338/does-react-native-compile-javascript-into-java-for-android) covers that quite concisely while the [linked post](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-react-native-bridge-concept-e9526066ddb8) would give you an extensive description of the concept.

Comment: Hi @Siavas, I did the exact same thing for code obfuscation. But the obfuscation seems doesn't work when I check the bundle.js. I have created a question to StackOverflow for that. Could you check, please? Here is the link --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64265280/how-to-obfuscate-react-native-bundle-js-in-ios

Comment: `npm install react-native-obfuscating-transformer --dev`
Use this command as this is dev dependency.

Answer (score 10):

The above answer by **@Siavas** covered most of the things however the metro plugin `react-native-obfuscating-transformer` doesn't seems to be obfuscating the `index.android.bundle`, you can try [obfuscator-io-metro-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/obfuscator-io-metro-plugin) this seems to be working fine. it is also based on  `javascript-obfuscator`.

you need to include the following config in `metro.config.js`

```
const jsoMetroPlugin = require("obfuscator-io-metro-plugin")(
  {
    // these option are obfuscation options from javascript-obfuscator
    compact: false,
    sourceMap: true,
    controlFlowFlattening: true,
    controlFlowFlatteningThreshold: 1,
    numbersToExpressions: true,
    simplify: true,
    shuffleStringArray: true,
    splitStrings: true,
    stringArrayThreshold: 1,
  },
  {
    runInDev: false /* optional */,
    logObfuscatedFiles: true /* optional generated files will be located at ./.jso */,
  }
);
 
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
  ...jsoMetroPlugin,
};
```

Comment: Does this library also obfuscate the iOS project, or only Android?

Comment: See this for IOS: https://github.com/whoami-shubham/obfuscator-io-metro-plugin/issues/2#issuecomment-932389379

Comment: I tried this but for some reason, even though the obfuscator runs, the index.android.bundle still contains comments like "// Original Name: xxx Environment: rxx". How can I prevent that?