# How to obfuscate code in react-native for IOS

Tags: javascript, react-native, obfuscation

I have been trying to obfuscate the code for a while by using [react-native-obfuscating-transformer](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/react-native-obfuscating-transformer). Everything seems okay but when I check the bundle.js. I can't see any obfuscated code.

PS: Currently, I try only for IOS.

Here are my config files.

**metro.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    transformer: {
        babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('./transformer'),
        getTransformOptions: async () => ({
            transform: {
                experimentalImportSupport: false,
                inlineRequires: false,
            },
        }),
    },
};
```

**transformer.js**

```
const obfuscatingTransformer = require('react-native-obfuscating-transformer');

module.exports = obfuscatingTransformer({
    upstreamTransformer: require('metro-react-native-babel-transformer'),
    enableInDevelopment: true,
    obfuscatorOptions: {
        compact: true,
        controlFlowFlattening: true,
        controlFlowFlatteningThreshold: 0.75,
        deadCodeInjection: true,
        deadCodeInjectionThreshold: 0.4,
        debugProtection: false,
        debugProtectionInterval: false,
        disableConsoleOutput: true,
        identifierNamesGenerator: 'hexadecimal',
        log: false,
        numbersToExpressions: true,
        renameGlobals: false,
        rotateStringArray: true,
        selfDefending: true,
        shuffleStringArray: true,
        simplify: true,
        splitStrings: true,
        splitStringsChunkLength: 10,
        stringArray: true,
        stringArrayEncoding: ['base64'],
        stringArrayWrappersCount: 2,
        stringArrayWrappersChainedCalls: true,
        stringArrayWrappersType: 'variable',
        stringArrayThreshold: 0.75,
        transformObjectKeys: true,
        unicodeEscapeSequence: false,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out how to make it work after several test.

**my react and react native version:**

```
 "react": "16.9.0",
 "react-native": "0.61.5",
```

**install other dependencies needed:**

```
npm install babylon --save
npm install --save babel-traverse
```

**transformer.js**

```
const obfuscatingTransformer = require("react-native-obfuscating-transformer")
const filter = filename => { 
  return filename.startsWith("src");
};

module.exports = obfuscatingTransformer({
// this configuration is based on https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator
  obfuscatorOptions:{
    compact: true,
    controlFlowFlattening: false,
    deadCodeInjection: false,
    debugProtection: false,
    debugProtectionInterval: false,
    disableConsoleOutput: true,
    identifierNamesGenerator: 'hexadecimal',
    log: false,
    renameGlobals: false,
    rotateStringArray: true,
    selfDefending: true,
    shuffleStringArray: true,
    splitStrings: false,
    stringArray: true,
    stringArrayEncoding: ['base64'],
    stringArrayThreshold: 0.75,
    unicodeEscapeSequence: false
  },
  upstreamTransformer: require('metro-react-native-babel-transformer'),
  emitObfuscatedFiles: false,
  enableInDevelopment: true,
  filter: filter,
  trace: true
})
```

**metro.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("./transformer")   // add here the transformer.js
  },
};
```

**NOTE:**

set emitObfuscatedFiles to true in obfuscatorOptions to emit the obfuscated versions of files alongside their originals, for comparison.

If you're building in release, you can also compare the generated **index.android.bundle** (located in \android\app\build\generated\assets\react\release) with and without using the react-native-obfuscating-transformer using online diff tool to see the difference

Comment: Thanks for the very clear explanation. Code obfuscation looks like working well but app crashes. I got exaclty same error with this guy https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/react-native-obfuscating-transformer/issues/35

Comment: @HalilİbrahimÖzdoğan can you tell me your nodejs version and react-native-obfuscating-transformer version?

Comment: @HalilİbrahimÖzdoğan can you try to remove package-lock.json and completely reinstall all your node_modules and check?

Comment: I am grateful to you for being helpful. Removing package-lock.json and node_modules didn't fix the problem. But I changed forked the project and changed the version of `javascript-obfuscator` dependency. Right now, it's working well. Since your solution helped me, indeed. I am going to mark this answer.

Comment: Obfuscating src\screens\helloWorld.js
error src\screens\helloWorld.js: function (prevType) {
  this.state.exprAllowed = false;

  if (prevType === types._let || prevType === types._c...<omitted>...
} could not be cloned.
Error: function (prevType) {
  this.state.exprAllowed = false;

  if (prevType === types._let || prevType === types._c...<omitted>...
} could not be cloned.    andy idea how to solve it ?

Comment: @JayThummar I am also facing same error, have you got the solution ?

Comment: @MuhammadNuman which offline diff tool can I use to compare the 2 index.android.bundle files please?

Comment: @instanceof you can use beyondcompare tool for two file

Answer (score 4):

I was not able to get my js code obfuscated with this method, but I think I managed to do it with this package. I am interested in hearing your opinions.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/obfuscator-io-metro-plugin

Comment: Basically everything @Muhammad Numan did. I think it might have not choosen the right folder to obfuscate (even though I filtered the folder), but I really am nor sure. The metro plugin works perfectly though :)

Comment: Agree bro, this plugin is better check https://npmtrends.com/@heroai/react-native-obfuscating-transformer-vs-obfuscator-io-metro-plugin-vs-react-native-obfuscating-transformer-clone-vs-react-native-obfuscator-vs-react-native-obscure it has been updated last two months ago