# ling react-native I get the following error (on windows)?

Tags: react-native

C:\Users\Asus>npm install -g react-native
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0

added 4 packages, changed 713 packages, and audited 718 packages in 3m

17 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because this package has been deprecated if you check this [package link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es)

[image]

That's the reason why you are getting the warning.

If you are looking into obfuscating the code check out the following answer

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54282723/2930834