# Does React Native translates JavaScript into native code in the background?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I am currently developing a hybrid mobile application using the React Native library. But I am not sure how it executes in the Android or iOS platforms just like how a native application executes. So could someone please help me understand the background process of react-native. Is it translating the JavaScript code written into native code(Java or Objective C) and then compile & executes the native code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124338/does-react-native-compile-javascript-into-java-for-android

Comment: @Yossi - The link provided was helpful. Thank you !