# Where are all the React Native compiled class files?

Tags: android, react-native, apk, dex

I have a React Native project with about 3 or 4 screens.

After I decompiled the generated Android classes.dex file, I only found two Java classes. If I'm correct that React Native compiles your components to native Android classes, where are all the Android classes for those screens?

[image]

Please note: The APK was bundled correctly as it runs fine on Android devices.

Also I ran the following command to create the APK:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js \
            --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
            --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think React Native will not compiles your components to native Android classes...

Comment: Here is a similar problem： [Does React Native compile JavaScript into Java for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124338/does-react-native-compile-javascript-into-java-for-android)

Comment: Hi. Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: React Native will not compile your components to native Android classes. Here is a similar question： [Does React Native compile JavaScript into Java for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124338/does-react-native-compile-javascript-into-java-for-android)