# Is React Native still interpreted or now it's compilation-based?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In 2016 the answer was " interpreted " based on this question [Does React Native compile JavaScript into Java for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124338/does-react-native-compile-javascript-into-java-for-android). However, since 2022 React Native has introduced new architecture:

> The New Architecture dropped the concept of The Bridge in favor of another communication mechanism: the JavaScript Interface (JSI). The JSI is an interface that allows a JavaScript object to hold a reference to a C++ and vice-versa.
> Once an object has a reference to the other one, it can directly invoke methods on it. So, for example, a C++ object can now ask a JavaScript object to execute a method in the JavaScript world and viceversa.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/the-new-architecture/why

To my understanding, it's still an interpreted approach. But some articles and one master's thesis I read today claim that it's compilation-based without clear explanation of the statement. Perhaps my understanding is wrong. So is React Native still interpreted or now it's compiled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React Native still includes Javascript code which is executed in a JS interpreter, which one specifically will be open thanks to the changes of the new architecture.

Here's a neat article which compares the old and new architectures in sufficient detail: https://medium.com/coox-tech/deep-dive-into-react-natives-new-architecture-fb67ae615ccd

Comment: Thank you for sharing this article, it's indeed good!

Answer (score 1):

React Native is still primarily an interpreted language, even with the introduction of the new JSI-based architecture. The JSI allows for more direct communication between JavaScript and native code, but it does not change the fact that the JavaScript code is still interpreted at runtime.