# React native continuous integration (supports iOS & Android)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, continuous-integration

What is a good site for continuous integration that supports both iOS and Android for react native development?

The last question I found for this topic was three years ago so I think it's time for a more up to date answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Microsoft App Center https://appcenter.ms
2. bitrise https://www.bitrise.io
3. circleci https://circleci.com
4. NEVERCODE https://nevercode.io
5. Your own Jenkins on AWS: http://www.ziniostech.com/continuous-integration-react-native-application-aws-jenkins-bitbucketandroid/

and more...

Also check this Q/A: [Continuous Integration with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381230/continuous-integration-with-react-native)